# Checkbox label is being displayed on next line

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a checkboxlist, and I created a javascript function that will add checkbox to the checkboxlist, 
here's the code

```
function add1()
{
  var ques = document.getElementById('Questions_que1');
  var container = document.getElementById('Questions_wh1');
  var checkbox = document.createElement('input');

  checkbox.type = "checkbox";
  checkbox.name = "que1";
  checkbox.value = ques.value;
  checkbox.id = "id";

  var label = document.createElement('label');

  label.htmlFor = "id";

  label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ques.value));

  container.appendChild(checkbox);
  container.appendChild(label);   
}
```

but the problem is that the checkbox label is being displayed on the next line instead of after the checkbox on the same line..

what am I doing wring here???

Comment: Try to add checkbox.style.display="inline"; . You could check if the checkbox element has been applied "display: block" style.

Comment: I tried that display="inline", and I can see display:inline in source code. but still no effect, it's still below the checkbox...

Comment: I think it's because of the last two statements...

Comment: What's the width of the container?